# This is a product manager that add products, sorts, lists and makes the list searchable

Tags: c#, beginner

I have finished with my product but I am not that trained in refactoring, cleaning up my code and spot redundancy so I would really appreciate some help.

```
namespace Product_manager
{
    // Product class represents a product with category, name, and price.
    class Product
    {
        public Product(string category, string name, decimal price)
        {
            Category = category;
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
        }

        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    class ProductManager
    {
        // List of all products
        private static readonly List<Product> Products = new List<Product>();

        // Add a new product.
        public void AddProduct(string category, string name, decimal price)
        {
            // Checks if the name is similar to already stored products.
            if (Products.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("A product with the same name already exists. Please enter a unique name.");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
                return;
            }

            // Adding successfully!
            Products.Add(new Product(category, name, price));
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("The product was successfully added!");
            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
        }

        // Method to display all products in the list.
        public void ShowProducts()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

            // Print the header with column names.
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", "Category", "Name", "Price");
            Console.ResetColor();

            foreach (var product in Products.OrderBy(p => p.Price))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{product.Category,-20} {product.Name,-20} {product.Price,-20}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

            // Print the total amount of all products' prices.
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", "", "Total amount:", Products.Sum(p => p.Price));
        }

        // Method to add more products interactively.
        public void AddMoreProducts()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
            Console.WriteLine("To enter a new product - follow the steps | To quit - Enter Q");
            Console.ResetColor();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter product details (or 'q' to quit adding more products):");
                Console.Write("Category: ");
                string? category = Console.ReadLine();

                if (category?.ToLower() == "q")
                    break;

                string? name = null;
                while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                {
                    Console.Write("Product Name: ");
                    name = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a non-empty product name.");
                }

                if (name != null)
                {
                    decimal price;
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Price: ");
                        if (decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out price))
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid price. Please enter a valid decimal number.");
                        }
                    }

                    AddProduct(category!, name, price);
                }
            }
        }

        // Search method
        public void SearchProduct(string searchTerm)
        {
            var results = Products
                .Where(p => p.Name.Equals(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                .ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("\nSearch Results:");

            // Print the header with column names in green.
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", "Category", "Name", "Price");
            Console.ResetColor();

            // Mark the search result in purple.
            foreach (var product in Products.OrderBy(p => p.Price))
            {
                if (results.Any(p => p.Name.Equals(product.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{product.Category,-20} {product.Name,-20} {product.Price,-20}");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.ResetColor();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{product.Category,-20} {product.Name,-20} {product.Price,-20}");
                }
            }

            Console.ResetColor();
            Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 50));
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            
            ProductManager manager = new ProductManager();

            // Loop to add more products.
            while (true)
            {
                manager.AddMoreProducts();

                // Display all products in the list.
                manager.ShowProducts();

                Console.Write("Do you want to add more products? (y/n): ");
                string? choice = Console.ReadLine();

                if (choice?.ToLower() != "y")
                    break;
            }

            // Loop to search for products.
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the product name to search (or 'q' to quit searching): ");
                string? searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

                if (searchTerm != null && searchTerm.ToLower() != "q")
                {
                    manager.SearchProduct(searchTerm);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The **ProductManager** class is doing too much: adding, displaying and searching.
You can split that into different classes, something like:

- ProductAdder
- ProductSearcher
- ProductGetter

Your methods are also doing multiple things which violates the SRP. Example: **SearchProduct()**

- Performs the search query.
- Prints the results table layout (like header).
- Prints the actual table with products.

This actually leads you to repeat code like this:

```
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", "Category", "Name", "Price");
        Console.ResetColor();
```

So, I would also create a class to manage the table rendering.

The method **AddMoreProducts()** has also a couple of problems:

- It handles user input.
- It handles input validation, (which I think you don't do when it is a single product add) - this may call for a validator class.
- It holds program flow with *while(true)*.

### In Short:

- Split logic into more classes to keep your classes with a single responsability.
- Do not mix user input handling, presentation and validation with business logic. (If tomorrow you would need to use a different UI but keep the logic, with your current code it would be much harder to do). Also, much harder (or even impossible) to correctly unit test.
- Your methods should also do a single thing.
- IMO, you should not mix the program flow with business logic also, this makes it harder to read, debug and understand.

Answer (score 1):

**Class Singularity Yields Clarity**

> product manager that add products, sorts, lists and makes the list searchable

Products class will do all of these *for itself*; the precept of single responsibility. ProjectManager [will tell (not ask)](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) Products what to do.

The ProjectManager will have clean, simple code because `Products` and `Product` classes are full of **S**ingle **R**esponsibility **P**rinciple

```
Products myProducts = new Products();

// prompt for product

myProducts.Add(new Product(aCategory, aName, aPrice));

// loop

myProducts.Sort();
console.WriteLine(myProducts);

Products toys = myProducts.FindByCategory('toys');
toys.SortByPrice();
console.WriteLine(toys);
```

The above code validates parameters, keeps the list unique by name, outputs the products with column headings, sorted,  w/ the total price on the end.

---

**.NET Collection Customization Basics**

.NET collections, in cooperation with `Object` polymorphism (overriding), are designed for customizing these functions.

*`Product` overrides*

- `Equals` for object identity, searching, and sorting
- `CompareTo` for sorting
- `ToString` for formatted textual output.  P.S. Very helpful during development/troubleshooting.

.

```
class Product {
  public Product (string category, string name, decimal price) {
    this.Name     = name ?? String.Empty;
    this.Category = category ?? "no Category";
    this.Price    = price;

    // do ALL validation tests required to create a valid object
    // with valid state - all instance variables set, at least to some default.
    // client code should not have to check for null. Do it here.
    // HIGHLY recommend String.Empty for string default. Method calls on null
    // throw exceptions, string.Empty does not.
  }

  public bool override Equals (Object other) {
    if (other == null) return false;

    Product theOther = other as Product;
    if ( theOther == null ) return false;

    return Name.Equals(other.Name);
  }

  public int override CompareTo(Object other) {
    if (other == null) return 1;

    Product theOther = other as Product;
    if (theOther == null) return 1;

    return Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
  }

  public string override ToString() {
    return "{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", Category, Name, Price);
  }
}
```

*Products collection*

- Composed with `List`. Per MSDN do not inherit `List`.
- `Add` ensures unique Product objects. Internally calls Product.Equals
- `Sort` internally calls Product.CompareTo
- `ToString` calls Product.ToString.

  - console.WriteLine calls `ToString` implicitly

.

```
class Products {
  protected List<Product> Products {get; set;}

  public Products() { Products = new List<Product>(); }


  // return bool to detect duplicate reject
  public void Add(Product newProduct) {
    if (newProduct == null) return;
    if (Products.Contains(newProduct)) return;  // calls Equals
   
    Products.Add(newProduct)
  }

  public Product FindByName(string findMe) {
    return Products.Find(x -> x.Name == findMe);
  }

  public Products FindByCategory(string findMe) {
    return Products.Find(x -> x.Category == findMe);
  }

  public void Sort() { Products.Sort(); } // calls CompareTo

  public void SortByPrice() {
     Products.Sort( x -> x.Price );
  } 

  public decimal PriceTotal() {
    decimal total = 0;

    forEach(var product in Products) total += product.price;

    return total;
  }

  public string override ToString() {
    StringBuilder me = new StringBuilder();
    me.AppendLine("{0,-20} {1,-20} {2,-20}", "Category", "Name", "Price");

    forEach (var product in Products) {
      me.Append(product);    // calls ToString
      me.Append("/n");
    }

    me.AppendLine("/n Total Product Prices: {0}", Products.PriceTotal());

    return me.ToString();
  } 
} // Products
```

**Read MSDN collection documentation. It is a treasure trove of OO goodness**